# How to carry a component's generic definition over React-Redux' `connect`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-redux, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a general API-querying wrapper component helper, and want to type it generically (with TypeScript) so as to support type-checking the parameters and results of specific API endpoints. I can get this working, except for the React-Redux `connect` wrapper, over which I can't seem to carry the generic definition of the helper.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
// import Api from "../somewhere";
declare const Api: { fetch: (params: any) => any };

interface Props<Result, Params> {
  accessToken?: string;
  params: Params;
  children: (fetchState: { loading: boolean; result?: Result; error?: any }) => React.ReactNode;
}

function ApiQueryComponent<Result, Params>({
  accessToken,
  params,
  children
}: Props<Result, Params>) {
  if (accessToken) {
    // Actually use the API here ...
    const promise = Api.fetch({ accessToken, params }) as Promise<Result>;
    const result = ({ id: 5, title: "shoes" } as unknown) as Result;
    return <div>{children({ loading: false, result })}</div>;
  } else {
    return <div>Please login first</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: { accessToken?: string }) {
  return {
    accessToken: state.accessToken
  };
}

export const ApiQuery = connect(mapStateToProps)(ApiQueryComponent);

// ======
// UI.tsx
// ======

declare const Product: React.ComponentType<{ product: any }>;
declare interface IProduct {}

// Does not type-check, "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 2"
export function UI() {
  return (
    <ApiQuery<IProduct, { id: number }> params={{ id: 5 }}>
      {({ loading, result: product, error }) => {
        if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
        else if (error) return <div>Error :(</div>;
        else return <Product product={product} />;
      }}
    </ApiQuery>
  );
}

// Type-checks as expected, `product` is an `IProduct`
export function UI2() {
  return (
    <ApiQueryComponent<IProduct, { id: number }> params={{ id: 5 }}>
      {({ loading, result: product, error }) => {
        if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
        else if (error) return <div>Error :(</div>;
        else return <Product product={product} />;
      }}
    </ApiQueryComponent>
  );
}
```

In this code, `UI2` works as expected, you can tell it what the types are of your params and data. But in `UI`, because of the `connect` wrapper, this information cannot be specified.

Does anybody know how to carry over the generics? I've tried wrapping the `connect`ed component in various ways, but haven't gotten it working yet :(